# how to update text form with image

Tags: php, forms

how to update text form with image

im trying to update text with image
now this code working fine with text and also image update perfectly

but image is not showing in edit from

example  edit form

- Name:demo
- Father Name:demo
- address: demo

  Photo   - chose file- i want here image name like photo.jpg

image is also there in database but not showing here in edit form

how can i do this please tell me to fix this issue thanks

this is form code

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
     <div>
     <p><strong>ID:</strong> <?php echo $id; ?></p>
    <div>
       <p><span class="style9"><strong>Teacher No:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
         <input name="teacherno" type="text" value="<?php echo $teacherno; ?>" size="50" />
       </p>
       <p><span class="style9"><strong>Teacher Name:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
         <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" size="50" />
       </p>
       <p><span class="style9"><strong>Education:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
         <input name="education" type="text" value="<?php echo $education; ?>" size="50" />
       </p>
       <p><span class="style9"><strong>Father Name:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
         <input name="fathername" type="text" value="<?php echo $fathername; ?>" size="50" />
       </p>
          <p><span class="style9"><strong>Salary:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
         <input name="salary" type="text" value="<?php echo $salary; ?>" size="50" />
        </p>
        <p><span class="style9"><strong>Date Of Birth :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
          <input name="age" type="text" value="<?php echo $age; ?>" size="50" />
       </p>
          <p><span class="style9"><strong>Teach Class :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
            <input name="classteacher" type="text" value="<?php echo $classteacher; ?>" size="50" />
       </p>
       <p><span class="style9"><strong>Phone No :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
         <input name="phone" type="text" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>"/>
       </p>
       <p><span class="style9"><strong>Date Of Join :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
         <input id="fullDate" name="dateofjoin" type="text" value="<?php echo $dateofjoin; ?>" size="50" />
       </p>
        <p><span class="style9"><strong>Home Address :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
           <textarea name="address" cols="50"><?php echo $address; ?></textarea>
       </p>
        <p><span class="style9"><strong>N.I.C No:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
          <input name="nic" type="text" value="<?php echo $nic; ?>" size="50" />
       </p>
        <span class="style9"><strong>Branch:</strong></span><strong> *</strong>
        <input name="branch" type="text" value="<?php echo $branch; ?>" size="50">
    <span class="style9"><strong>Photo:</strong></span><strong> *</strong>
                 <input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $photo; ?>" size="50">
                <input type="file" name="photo"> 
        <br/>
       <p class="style1">* required</p>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
     </div>
     </form>
```

and this is php code

```
<?php
 }

 //This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "images/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form

$photo=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}


 // connect to the database
 include('connect-db.php');

 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 // confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
 if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
 {
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $teacherno = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['teacherno']));
 $name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
 $education = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['education']));
 $salary = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['salary']));
 $classteacher = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['classteacher']));
 $dateofjoin = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['dateofjoin']));
 $nic = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['nic']));
 $address = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']));
 $age = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['age']));
 $fathername = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fathername']));
 $phone = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
 $branch = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['branch']));
 $photo = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_FILES['photo']['name']));

 // check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in
 if ($teacherno == '' || $name == '')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 //error, display form
 renderForm($id, $teacherno, $name, $education, $salary, $classteacher, $dateofjoin, $nic, $address, $age, $fathername, $phone, $branch, $photo, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("UPDATE teacher SET teacherno='$teacherno', name='$name', education='$education', salary='$salary', classteacher='$classteacher', dateofjoin='$dateofjoin', nic='$nic', address='$address', age='$age', phone='$phone', branch='$branch', photo='$photo' WHERE id='$id'")
 or die(mysql_error()); 



 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: view.php"); 
 }
 }
 else
 {
 // if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
 {

 // get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
 {
 // query db
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE id=$id")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 // check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
 if($row)
 {

 // get data from db
 $teacherno = $row['teacherno'];
 $name = $row['name']; 
 $education = $row['education']; 
 $salary = $row['salary']; 
 $classteacher = $row['classteacher']; 
 $dateofjoin = $row['dateofjoin']; 
 $nic = $row['nic']; 
 $address = $row['address']; 
 $age = $row['age']; 
 $fathername = $row['fathername']; 
 $phone = $row['phone']; 
 $branch = $row['branch']; 
 $photo = $row['photo']; 


 // show form
 renderForm($id, $teacherno, $name, $education, $salary, $classteacher, $dateofjoin, $nic, $address, $age, $fathername, $phone, $branch, $photo, '');
 }
 else
 // if no match, display result
 {
 echo "No results!";
 }
 }
 else
 // if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error
 {
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to show the actual image? Or show the image path or name after submit? Your question does not make that clear.

Comment: i want image name who are already in database

Answer (score 0):

I'm not goint to adapt all your code. I think that with these lines you've enought to underestand it! Check it out and tell to us! :)

**FORM**

```
<?
// You've to pass a parameter to get if is a form for edit teacher or for new teacher
$edit = $_POST['edit'];
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="edit" value="<? $edit ?>"/>

    <div>
        <p><strong>ID:</strong> <?php echo $id; ?></p>
    <div>
    <p>
        <span class="style9"><strong>Teacher No:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
        <input name="teacherno" type="text" value="<?php echo $teacherno; ?>" size="50" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="style9"><strong>Teacher Name:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
        <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" size="50" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="style9"><strong>Education:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
        <input name="education" type="text" value="<?php echo $education; ?>" size="50" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="style9"><strong>Father Name:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
        <input name="fathername" type="text" value="<?php echo $fathername; ?>" size="50" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="style9"><strong>Salary:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
        <input name="salary" type="text" value="<?php echo $salary; ?>" size="50" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="style9"><strong>Date Of Birth :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
        <input name="age" type="text" value="<?php echo $age; ?>" size="50" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="style9"><strong>Teach Class :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
        <input name="classteacher" type="text" value="<?php echo $classteacher; ?>" size="50" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="style9"><strong>Phone No :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
        <input name="phone" type="text" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="style9"><strong>Date Of Join :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
        <input id="fullDate" name="dateofjoin" type="text" value="<?php echo $dateofjoin; ?>" size="50" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="style9"><strong>Home Address :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
        <textarea name="address" cols="50"><?php echo $address; ?></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="style9"><strong>N.I.C No:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
        <input name="nic" type="text" value="<?php echo $nic; ?>" size="50" />
    </p>
    <span class="style9"><strong>Branch:</strong></span><strong> *</strong>
    <input name="branch" type="text" value="<?php echo $branch; ?>" size="50">

    <span class="style9"><strong>Photo:</strong></span><strong> *</strong>
    <?
    if ($edit) {
        // This will show a image that we have on the ddbb
        ?><img src="$path_images.$img" /><?
    }
    ?>
    <input type="file" name="photo" /> 

    <br/>
    <p class="style1">* required</p>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
// connect to the database
include('connect-db.php');

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "images/";


// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
    // confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
    if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
    {
        // get form data, making sure it is valid
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $teacherno = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['teacherno']));
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
        $education = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['education']));
        $salary = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['salary']));
        $classteacher = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['classteacher']));
        $dateofjoin = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['dateofjoin']));
        $nic = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['nic']));
        $address = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']));
        $age = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['age']));
        $fathername = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fathername']));
        $phone = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
        $branch = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['branch']));
        $photo = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_FILES['photo']['name']));

        // check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in
        if ($teacherno == '' || $name == '')
        {
        // generate error message
        $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

        //error, display form
        renderForm($id, $teacherno, $name, $education, $salary, $classteacher, $dateofjoin, $nic, $address, $age, $fathername, $phone, $branch, $photo, $error);
    }else{
         // save the data to the database
         mysql_query("UPDATE teacher SET teacherno='$teacherno', name='$name', education='$education', salary='$salary', classteacher='$classteacher', dateofjoin='$dateofjoin', nic='$nic', address='$address', age='$age', phone='$phone', branch='$branch', photo='$photo' WHERE id='$id'")
         or die(mysql_error()); 
         // once saved, redirect back to the view page
         header("Location: view.php"); 
     }
}else{
    // if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
    echo 'Error!';
}


if ($_POST['edit'])
{
    if (($_FILES["img"]["error"] != 0) or if($_FILES["img"]["error"] != 4))
    {
        // we update everyting without the image!!
        mysql_query("UPDATE teacher SET teacherno='$teacherno', name='$name', education='$education', salary='$salary', classteacher='$classteacher', dateofjoin='$dateofjoin', nic='$nic', address='$address', age='$age', phone='$phone', branch='$branch' WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error()); 

    }else{
        // we update everyting without the image!!
        $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
        $photo = ($_FILES['photo']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
        {   
             mysql_query("UPDATE teacher SET teacherno='$teacherno', name='$name', education='$education', salary='$salary', classteacher='$classteacher', dateofjoin='$dateofjoin', nic='$nic', address='$address', age='$age', phone='$phone', branch='$branch', photo='$photo' WHERE id='$id'")
            or die(mysql_error()); 
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: dear this is edit form to update all text and image and when i update only text and submit the form image is not save in database... example name:demoname fathername:demofathername photo:demo.jpg this is already save in mysql table but when i update the text info using edit from and submit the result then i check mysql table example name:demoxyz fathername:demofathername photo: in here image is not found

Comment: If you receive an empty file input you don't have to update the image of ddbb. Only if you receive some file. You can check if received nothing with: `if($_FILES["img"]["error"] != 0)` or `if($_FILES["img"]["error"] != 4)`

Comment: Something like this: `UPDATE table_name SET img='name_img.jpg' WHERE pk_product = $pk;`

Comment: Of course that until that you've to do a `SELECT img FROM table_name WHERE pk_product = $pk;` or if you do a `SELECT * FROM img WHERE pk_product = $pk` then you've to do: 
`while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result){
$img = $row['img'];
}
$sql = UPDATE table_name SET img='name_img.jpg' WHERE pk_product = $pk;
$res = mysql_query($sql);`

Comment: Did you fix it with that? :)

Comment: no i dont understand how to fix it can u edit in to my code becz ur code is differnt

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in  on line 131 and line 131 is    if (($_FILES["img"]["error"] != 0) or if($_FILES["img"]["error"] != 4))

Comment: I've an error on this line, the correct is this: if (($_FILES["img"]["error"] != 0) || ($_FILES["img"]["error"] != 4))

Answer (score 0):

***Just try with the following :***

```
<p>
   <span class="style9"><strong>Photo:</strong></span><strong> *</strong>
   <input type="hidden" name="size" value="<?php echo $photo; ?>" size="50">
   <input type="file" name="photo"><img src="users_photo/<?php ($photo ? $photo : 'default.jpg');?>" border="0"> 
</p>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: but when i dont change in image and update only text and image is already save in database after the submit image remove the database thats the problem dear

Comment: You need to check before updating the image field in a database, 
Example, 
$file = $_FILES['file'];
$name = $file['name'];
$path = "/uploads/" . basename($name);
if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path)) {
// Move succeed.
} else {
// Move failed. Possible duplicate?
}....like this.